# Let v1,...,vp,w1,...,wk ∈ Rn. Prove that if v1,...,vp ∈ Span{w1,...,wk}, then Span{v1,...,vp} ⊆ Span{w1,...,wk}.

Tags: linear-algebra

My approach is to let x be v1, ... , vp and let y = w1, ... , wk. In the end, I would substitute it all back in to prove that it all works. I'm kind of lost in the middle however it would be great if y'all could help me out.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a span of vectors?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: It might be nicer to split this result up. Show first that $\operatorname{Span}\{w_1, \ldots, w_k\}$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Then, show that if $W$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $v_1, \ldots, v_p \in W$, then $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_p\} \subseteq W$. By splitting the result in this way, you avoid having double sums.

Comment: The title doesn't serve simply as the first sentence of the body of your Question. Please use the body to give a fairly self-contained problem statement (the setup and the goal) and to provide context for your Question (where did the problem arise?  why is it difficult/interesting/important? Or what did you research/try before posting?).

Answer (score 1):

For this, you want to show that elements of $ \operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_p\} $ are in the span of $ \{w_1,\ldots,w_k\} $. Thus, if $ x\in \operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_p\} $, then for some real numbers $ \{a_i:1\leq i \leq p\} $, $$ x = \sum_{i=1}^p a_i v_i $$ We then know that each $ v_i $ is in $ \operatorname{span}\{w_1,\ldots,w_k\} $, so for each $ i $, we have real numbers $ \{b^i_j:1\leq j\leq k\} $ such that $$ v_i = \sum_{j=1}^k b^i_j w_j $$ We can substitute these sums into the sum for $ x $, distribute and re-group coefficients, and then we will be done as $ x $ was arbitrary.